# Most compact and fastest way to store my string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large hexidecimal (16 byte, 32 hex digits) data item that always has the format:

```
00d980113901429fa6de7fb7e2da705a
```

This is coming in as an ASCII string from my source (i.e., the zero above is character zero 0x30, not 0x00), and I would like to know peoples' opinions on the best way (irt storage and speed) to store this in PostgreSQL.

The obvious thing to do is to just store it as a varchar, but storing it in a binary form would definitely save space. Would I see performance gains from select and insert by storing it in a binary form? Would bytea or bit be better? Is there a difference between these two in terms of internal representation?

Another idea would be to store it as two bigint/int8 or four integer/int4, split up into multiple columns.

Space and time are an issue as I have MANY of these (upwards of a trillion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare these two tables of 10M records:

```
create table test (a int8 not null, b int8 not null, primary key(a,b));
insert into test
  select generate_series(1,10000000), generate_series(1,10000000);
select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('test'));
```

```
723 MB
```

```
create table test_bytea (a bytea not null);
insert into test_bytea
  select decode(lpad(to_hex(a),16,'0')||lpad(to_hex(b),16,'0'),'hex') from test;
alter table test_bytea add primary key (a);
select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('test_bytea'));
```

```
804 MB
```

A `bytea` with index is 11% bigger than `2*int8`. This isn't much, but it means that 11% less rows will be in cache. And sequentional scans will be 11% slower etc.

If your data does not change maybe you should consider a flat file storage of sorted values instead of database - this will be only 152MB per 10M records and searching will be O(log(n)).

Comment: Even with a trillion rows, I wouldn't do this.  You're avoiding BYTEA's length-header in exchange for two fixed-width INT8's, but all your queries and foreign keys become more complicated.  Personally I would pay the 11% tax to keep things simpler.  Or you can switch to MySQL where BINARY(16) will have the same performance as two INT8 fields.

Comment: Bytea isn't much easier to work with, as it needs escaping or prepared queries. Comparisons of bytea will probably also be slower than 2*int8, as it probably checks byte by byte instead of 8 byte chunks and also needs to check for size.

Answer (score 1):

You have to determine what the most common use for the data is, in order to determine the appropriate data type.  A conversion away from the data type means that an index referencing the column is useless.

Comment: I can mold how we use/query the data to accommodate the representation used. An increase in space/time efficiency is worth it.

Comment: If you create a function index on the conversion, then its not useless.

Comment: @rfusca: True, but DBAs loath function based indexes IME.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect BYTEA will be 2x smaller for space, and 2x faster for comparisons (>, <, =) compared to a VARCHAR representation.

In other database engines you can even avoid the length-header overhead.  For example:

```
MS-SQL:   BINARY(16)
Oracle:   RAW(16)
MySQL:    BINARY(16)
```

Or if you like length-headers:

```
MS-SQL:   VARBINARY(16)
Oracle:   BLOB
MySQL:    VARBINARY(16)
```

PostgreSQL only supports BYTEA, so you always pay for the length-header, but I still go with BYTEA in this situation.